# Custom function to activate variable pitch mode in Org mode

Tags: faces, variable-pitch

I have this face definition that applies globally:

```
(set-face-attribute 'variable-pitch nil :family "Charis SIL Compact" :height 180)
```

The problem is that Elfeed and Mu4e also use the variable pitch mode and I don't want that.

I would like to create a custom function called `distraction-free-writing` that is bound to a key and when that key is pressed to activate the variable pitch mode in the current Org buffer and also set `olivetti-body-width` to a value of `60`.

For fixed pitched font the olivetti value is set to `80`, however variable pitch font is more condensed, so 80 characters fit in a `60` olivetti width.

Is it possible to make that face attribute local for a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand exactly what you want to do, but maybe something like this:

```lisp
(defvar-local my-distraction-free-writing-remap nil)

(defun my-distraction-free-writing ()
  (interactive)
  (if my-distraction-free-writing-remap
      (progn
        (face-remap-remove-relative
         my-distraction-free-writing-remap)
        (setq olivetti-body-width 80)
        (olivetti-mode 1)
        (setq my-distraction-free-writing-remap nil))
    (setq my-distraction-free-writing-remap
          (face-remap-add-relative 'variable-pitch
                                   :family "Charis SIL Compact"
                                   :height 180))
    (variable-pitch-mode 1)    
    (setq olivetti-body-width 60)
    (olivetti-mode 1)))
```

With `face-remap-add-relative` you can remap face attributes buffer-locally. So this redefines the face variable-pitch in the current buffer to have the given attributes, then turns on `variable-pitch-mode` and sets `olivetti-body-width`.

To bind it to a key: `(keymap-set org-mode-map "<f8>" #'my-distraction-free-writing)`.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for. I just had to add (olivetti-mode 1) otherwise the new width don't take effect. If I want this to be applied to all Org buffer do I need to attach the function to the `org-mode` hook?

Comment: I may ask too much but if I decide to bind it to a key, is it possible to make it toggle. For example if I press F8 to call the function as is now, but when I press F8 again to switch back to the previous fixed-pitch font "Hack" and set back olivetti to a width of 80.

Comment: Yes, you need to attach it to the hook. I changed the function so that now it should toggle.

Comment: I'm trying to bind it with the new syntax `(keymap-global-set "<f8>" 'my-distraction-free-writing)` but the results are not what I want.

Comment: What is the problem? The keybinding has no effect? It works for me. Try another binding, maybe something is overwriting yours.

Comment: Thank you. It works but I need to add `(olivetti-mode 1)` after `(setq olivetti-body-width 80)`  and move ` `(olivetti-mode 1)` after `(setq olivetti-body-width 60)`. Just for curiosity what is the purpose of the `my-distraction-free-writing-remap` variable?

Comment: OK. I'll make an edit to reflect that. The variable is used both for toggling and to store the active face remapping as this makes removing it again easier.

Comment: One more question, what does `org-mode-map` do? Does it restrict the key binding to Org mode buffers only? If so, that is fine.

Comment: Yes, exactly, to buffers with Org mode as active major mode.

Comment: This does not work properly for me. Toggling on works fine, but toggling `my-distraction-free-writing` off again does not restore the font to what it was before (the size is restored, but I get some non monospace font instead) and does also not turn `olivetti-mode` off. My standard font to which it should go back is set by `(setq doom-font (font-spec :family "DejaVu Sans Mono" :size 11.5)
      doom-variable-pitch-font (font-spec :family "sans"))`